# Difference between bind and var self=this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, bind, react-native

In my react native code, I am using both the `bind(this)` and `var self = this;` at multiple places across modules.

Both are solving the problem of resolving `this` keyword at the right places.

Here are my codes(2 code to perform the same functionality)-

1. Using `bind(this)`

   ```
   retval.then(function (argument) {
       console.log("argument"+JSON.stringify(argument));
       this.stateSetting(argument);
   }.bind(this));
   ```
2. Using `var self = this`

   ```
   var self = this;
   retval.then(function (argument) {
      console.log("argument"+JSON.stringify(argument));
      self.stateSetting(argument);
   });
   ```

Considering they both do the same job, I am curious to know what is the right way to do it? Is there an issue in using one or the other? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Both work fine.  I'd try to be somewhat consistent within a an app or at least a module.

Comment: ES6 arrow functions are a better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Robert :) Just wanted to know, if I do something like ```if(self === this)``` returns true. So, is there a way to destroy self? If it was an object I could have done - ```self = {}```. Should I point self to null in this case?

Comment: @Oriol Yes indeed, I would surely go with ES6 arrow function. Can you please share a pesudo code for the same? I am using arrow functions in lot of other places.

Comment: Simply: `retval.then((argument) => {
   console.log("argument"+JSON.stringify(argument));
   this.stateSetting(argument);
});`    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: WOW! That looks so clean. @lleaff Thanks for sharing the great taste of arrow functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you're targeting Node.js which implements ES2015 you are better off using arrow functions.
Arrow functions have what is called a *[lexical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this)* `this`, which means that the variable `this` in an arrow function is treated like a normal variable and will be *[closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)* when you create the function.

So your code becomes:

```
retval.then((argument) => {
    console.log("argument"+JSON.stringify(argument));
    // "this" will inherit the value of the outside scope
    this.stateSetting(argument); 
});
```

If targeting ES5 (older browsers), then I'd favor the `.bind` style rather than `var self = this`. It's more structured and closer to a functional approach, which makes the code easier to reason about like you must have discovered by using promises. It also seems to be [slightly more performant](https://web.archive.org/web/20171127144003/https://jsperf.com/bind-vs-self-closure).